# What happens when virtual destructors are declared, but have no implementation?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-destructor

In C++ we can perfectly declare a function in a header file without actually implementing it. This compiles fine and usually this doesn't provide any problems, however... I am wondering if it can cause a problem when a virtual destructor is not implemented.

When a virtual destructor is not implemented and, when in that case we delete the instance of derived class through a pointer of a base class, will the destructor of the derived class still be called?

E.g.

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    ~Derived(); // HAS NO IMPLEMENTATION
};

Base *b = new Derived();
delete b;
```

NB: AS POINTED OUT IN THE COMMENTS,THE ABOVE EXAMPLE DOES NOT LINK CORRECTLY. It is provided here to explain a situation in which I'm trying to gain more insight, however in practice during the linking process, this example will result in an `undefined reference to Derived` error.

Comment: _In C++ we can perfectly declare a function in a header file without actually implementing it. This compiles fine and usually this doesn't provide any problems_ Only if you don't call it. Otherwise you'll get a linker error. As it would in your example.

Comment: This comment probably just crossed the update I've made to code, note that I've changed the destructor of Base to be implemented and the destructor of Derived is not implemented.

Comment: Did you actually **try** your code? You should get a linker error, for example `undefined reference to `Derived::~Derived()'`.

Comment: Why don't you compile and link the code before posting the question?

Comment: [Ideone.com gave me a compile-time error for an undefined reference in the virtual table, due to no definition for `~Derived()`](http://ideone.com/puJJQi)

Comment: Technically, this program does compile into an object file (when expanded into a mcve). But you won't be able to succesfully link it into an executable unless you also link with another object file that does contain the definition.

Comment: Sharply commented! For correctness, I've updated the question with this info.

Comment: @Xirema: A link-time error, not a compile-time error.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yeah, if I could edit comments, I'd fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens when virtual destructors are declared, but have no implementation?

If the destructor is ever called (such as in your example), the program violates the one definition rule, and is therefore ill-formed. No diagnostic is required by the standard, and a compiler will not be able to tell that there is anything wrong. But luckily you'll probably be saved by a linker error.

> In C++ we can perfectly declare a function in a header file without actually implementing it.

This is true. But we cannot call such functions.

---

The *virtual* and *destructor* are not very relevant to the question. These rules apply to all functions.

Comment: Does it really violate the ODR? The ODR literally says *"No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, or template."* So if there's > 1 definitions, the ODR is violated. If there's 0 definitions, it's not the ODR which is being violated.

Comment: @ChristianHackl the ODR section is quite large and not limited to the first paragraph :) *"Every program shall contain **exactly one definition** of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used
in that program; no diagnostic required."*

Comment: True. That's paragraph 4. It never occurred to me that the ODR was basically that which formally requires definitions to exist.

Answer (score 6):

If you ever call `~Derived()` (such as by deleting `b`) you will get a linking errors since the symbols for the destructor does not exist. Since `~Base()` is virtual, `~Derived()` will still (try to) be called when you delete `b`. The absence of an implementation has no bearing on that.

Comment: Sharply seen, I've updated the question with that info.